# Recyclerview gives Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I was using recyclerveiw for my project. Everything was good but suddenly it start giving this error .

```
  --------- beginning of crash
07-02 15:27:49.029 3175-3175/satlaa.desijewellery E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: satlaa.desijewellery, PID: 3175
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{satlaa.desijewellery/satlaa.desijewellery.helper_activity.DJPhotos}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Error 
inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
```

**Build.Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '28.0.0'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "satlaa.desijewellery"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 12
    versionName "1.2"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res/layout/adapter', 'src/main/res/layout', 'src/main/res']
    }
}
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I searched all over the internet but did't get the solution.
I tried rebuilding and syncing the app. Updated all sdk tools, but nothing worked  out.
I removed all the java code, and it still gives error.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:splitMotionEvents="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: Please provide your XML class and the class contains your recyclerview

Comment: Check at line 43 of the `recyclerView`'s single item layout.

Comment: it's the recyclerview

Comment: did you checked after removing layout behaviour

Comment: try removing recyclerview dependency and check it again

Comment: @AshishSharma tried it many times

Comment: try downgrading it to 27.0.2

Comment: Aren't you using custom adapter for your `recyclerView`? If not then check your `activity_layout.xml` layout. The error is in the xml file, `recyclerView` isn't the issue.

Comment: @tahsinRupam yes it was . removed this lines -   
        app:fastScrollEnabled="true"

Comment: Still the error occurring? Then can you please check your layout file used in the adapter class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app:fastScrollEnabled="true"
```

This line from **XML** was giving error. Simply deleted this.